# Child div in parent div, float:left

Tags: css, html, css-float

Please take a look at my code: http://jsfiddle.net/XptrZ/
Why are'nt the blue divs inside the red one, and why the red one has height=0.
How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden` to parent

```css
.parent {
  background-color: gold;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Zoltan. It works perfectly. Can you give me a short explanation for this solution. I want to understand that. Thanks

Comment: The issue caused by the fact that floats are taken out of normal document flow. The `overflow: hidden` on the other side establishes a new block formatting context (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), and becomes the parent element to the floats again.

Answer (score 1):

Add one extra and empty  div to parent div with this format:

```
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add  display: table; inside parent. That'll work.

Comment: the `display: table` not supported in IE7 and below - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html "Below" - that's probably not a big issue, but you still have to consider IE7