# 2 Side by side DIVs (1line) stretching to right

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to build the liquid layout shown below in CSS.
[image: liquid layout]

The left column should stretch to all available space, and if it's possible, on same line.The column on right should became with the same width.

**I have already achieved a result very close to what I want.** Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/34/embedded/result/
But there are two problems. The height of both aligned DIVs should be equal. The first or second DIV should grow to be the same height as the other.

The second question is that when the width is not sufficient for 2 DIVs, I want the first (NomeEvento) div to be on top. and not the second div (DataEvento).

Comment: You may want to upvote people that have tried to help you.

Comment: How can I upvote? I've clicked on up icon at the left side of answer, but I received a message telleing that I can't upvote because I'm a new user.

Comment: I'm a new user. I don't know what it means when I click these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acomplished what I want using display table, table row and table cell in my divs.

Take a look. It's exactily what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/47/embedded/result/

Comment: Please Accept your answer so this Question is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly. Is the following layout something similar to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/5sjgf/

Comment: nope, the OP wants the left column to take all the remaining space

Comment: fair enough :) by the way, just for my information, couldn't you use clear:both in some way rather than overflow:hidden? (what does it doe exactly?)

Comment: You can use the `clearfix` method (just Google it). And about the `overflow: hidden` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8899571/981134 (read the comment)

Comment: In this example, the first thing is try to streach the left column. i.e: http://jsfiddle.net/5sjgf/5/ But I already created other better example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/5/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Here's more CSS to try out. If you wanted a margin on that left side. I added background colors to help differentiate.

```
div.NomeEvento {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.DataEvento {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%; 
    float:left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Can I have this for width? DataEvento get the available space to put contend and padding. NomeEvento get all remaining space. Should be a fixed margin between them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of extraneous CSS to me.  But maybe the other stuff is in there for a reason.  This works fine as the sum-total of your CSS though:

```
div.Evento {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div.NomeEvento {
    background: #eee;
    padding-right: 20%; /* the same as the right column width */
}

div.DataEvento {
    float:right;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

...BUT, if you're right-floating an element, place it *first* in the layout - here it's element class `DataEvento`:

```
<div class="Evento">
    <div class="DataEvento">@evento.Data</div>
    <div class="NomeEvento">@evento.Nome</div>
</div>​
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/J89Hp/

Cheers

Comment: It's like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/5/ but I want a fixed space between NomeEvento and DataEvento. And I want NomeEvento stretch in all available space. DataEvento should have a automatic width, just to show the contend and padding.

Comment: Ok, but my answer stands.  Yours simply has more CSS for styling - my example shows how to achieve the *layout*.  That was what your question was asking, I believe.

Comment: The purpouse of this is to create a liquid layout.

Comment: Madbreaks, It's almost there. Can I make this without fixing the % width? I want right div take a space to fit it's contend and a padding. Then, I want the left div taking all remaining space. should be a fixed space between them. If there isn't enought space to show both content at same line, left column should stay at top.